# Buttons for text area that change the font size however It only works of text selected by the user (like Microsoft office's font size selections)

Tags: html, fonts, size

This is the code I have for the font size buttons however I do need it to work on selected text only by the user and not change the font size of all letters in the text area (like Microsoft's font size selection in there word documents)

```
   <select onchange="textarea1.style.fontSize = this.value;" >
     <option value="12px" selected="selected">12</option>
     <option value="14px">14</option>
     <option value="16px">16</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

put the id="textarea1" into select

```
<select id="textarea1" onchange="textarea1.style.fontSize = this.value;" >
     <option value="12px" selected="selected">12</option>
     <option value="14px">14</option>
     <option value="16px">16</option>
</select>
```